# How to display a number in triangle fashion using progress-4gl

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

How to display a number or numbers in triangular pattern using progress4gl frame ?
Kindly help me .

E.g.

```
           1         OR             1
         1 1 1                    1 2 3
       1 1 1 1 1                 1 2 3 4 5
     1 1 1 1 1 1 1.            1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Using Frame How to display above patterns?

Answer (score 1):

Really courious about the use case .... but:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER NO-UNDO . 

DO  i = 1 TO 5:

    DISPLAY FILL (" ", (6 - i) * 2) + FILL ("1 ", i * 2 - 1) FORMAT "x(40)" WITH DOWN STREAM-IO.
    DOWN 1. 

END.
```

gets close.

Comment: Can you help me the second one ?

Comment: What kind of test is that? Sure ... how about voting for my replies then?

Answer (score 1):

```
DEFINE VARIABLE i      AS INTEGER NO-UNDO . 
DEFINE VARIABLE j      AS INTEGER NO-UNDO . 

DEFINE VARIABLE cLine AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(40)" NO-UNDO.

DO  i = 1 TO 5:

    cLine = FILL (" ", (6 - i) ) .

    DO j = 1 TO i:
        cLine = cLine + STRING (j * 2 - 1) + " ".
    END.

    DISPLAY cLine WITH DOWN STREAM-IO.
    DOWN 1. 

END.
```